Find the number of matrices over the finite field $\mathbb F_{19}$, whose minimal polynomial has a certain degree $m$.
I am collaborating with some colleagues to create a TACA (a test assessing knowledge in Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Elementary Group Theory) practice test. During this process, I devised the following problem (I'm not going to put it in that test):

Consider a matrix $ A $ in $ M_5(\mathbb{F}_{19}) $. Define $ n_A $ as the cardinality $ |\{p(A) : p \in \mathbb{Z}[X]\}| $, where $ |S| $ denotes the number of elements in set $ S $. Calculate $ \sum_{A \in M_5(\mathbb{F}_{19})} n_A $ modulo a specific number, for example, $ 10^5 $.

($19$ as a prime is nothing special. Researches on smaller prime like $p = 2, 5$ may be helpful.)
It can be observed that $ \{p(A) : p \in \mathbb{Z}[X]\} $ forms a linear subspace of $ M_5(\mathbb{F}_{19}) $, and its dimension equals to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $ A $, denoted $ m_A $. Therefore, $ n_A = 19^{m_A} $. If we determine the frequency of matrices $ A $ whose $ m $ value is $ x $ (where $ 0 \leq x \leq 5 $), we can then compute the solution.
In short, I need to find how much matrices $A \in M_{5}(\mathbb F_{19})$'s minimal polynomial has degree $k$, for all $0 \le k \le 5$.
I am finding it challenging to solve this problem, so it may be unsuitable for inclusion in the test. I am curious about:

How to approach solving this problem?
Whether it is feasible to solve this problem within the 3-hour time limit of TACA without the use of calculators.


For the first question: It's unclear what answer exactly you would like as you've presumably already worked the problem out.

For the second question: This question seems off topic here. Apart from that, disclosing yet-to-be-used test problems may comprise the test since participants might see the problem here. See also: "Contest problem" policy

@Ѕᴀᴀᴅ Strategies on how to approach a problem are absolutely on topic. Also, OP is not designing official practice problems, they are merely designing problems for a practice test. There is no risk if someone happens to see this problem.

@1048576 Since you're the one who devised this problem, do you have any reason to believe that it has a tractable solution? Not every counting question has an answer that can be found within the time available in an exam

This is in principle doable by casework on the generalized Jordan normal form / primary rational canonical form but for $M_5(\mathbb{F}_{19})$ I think it gets very tedious, probably too tedious for a practice test.
The casework is straightforward for $M_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. In this case the minimal polynomial can only have degree $1, 2$. In the first case $m_A(t) = t - \lambda$ (I am repurposing $m_A$ for the minimal polynomial itself rather than its degree) which happens iff $A = \lambda I$. So this case occurs $p$ times and gives $n_A = p$. If $A$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity then $\deg m_A = 2$ so this case occurs $p^4 - p$ times and gives $n_A = p^2$. Altogether we get
$$\sum_{A \in M_2(\mathbb{F}_p)} n_A = p^2 + (p^4 - p) p^2 = p^6 - p^3 + p^2.$$
For $M_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the problem is more interesting but this is as far as I would go on a practice test. The $\deg m_A = 1$ case is the same as above, and the $\deg m_A = 3$ case follows once we have counted the $\deg m_A = 2$ case. But as far as I can tell, in the $\deg m_A = 2$ case we actually need to do some work.
Without actually completing the calculation, here is how it should go. The cases are: $m_A(t) = (t - \lambda)^2$ has a repeated root, $m_A(t) = (t - \lambda)(t - \mu)$ has two distinct roots, or $m_A(t)$ is an irreducible quadratic. In the first case $A$ is conjugate to one of the two matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$$
and to count how many matrices we get we'd need to compute the stabilizer of each of these; this can be done but it would require some thinking (and the $5 \times 5$ generalization seems very tedious to me). In the second case $A$ is conjugate to one of the three matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \mu & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mu \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \mu & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mu \end{bmatrix}$$
and again we'd need to count how many matrices occur by computing the stabilizer (being careful not to overcount because $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are an unordered pair). In the final case, if $m_A(t) = t^2 - at - b$ is an irreducible quadratic, $A$ is conjugate to its companion matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b & 0 \\ 1 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and again we'd need to count how many matrices occur by computing the stabilizer.
So, the hard part of the argument (at least in this approach, and I can't think of another one) is computing the sizes of these stabilizers. This doesn't have to be brute-forced and can be done in a reasonably conceptual way (it helps to think about the corresponding $\mathbb{F}_p[A]$-module structure on $\mathbb{F}_p^3$) but the corresponding casework for $M_5$ would be really brutal.

Thanks for detailed answer.
